# iOS System UI text - Internationalization

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization, internationalization

Internationalizing my app, I’m working upon the following solution (method 2):

https://www.factorialcomplexity.com/blog/2015/01/28/how-to-change-localization-internally-in-your-ios-application.html

But, when I restart my app, the text contained in Navigation bars is not translated until I kill my app and I reopen it.

As you can see on images below. I have a UINavigationViewController. Then, restarting my app internally (reinstantiating my UINavigationViewController and using its corresponding bundle to my language set on NSUsersDefault) all text is translated excepting the text in my navigation bar (also happens when I try to delete on a table view and the delete text (red color) is not translated).

So, my question is: Anyone know how to force translate all the UI system text on iOS without having to kill and reopening the app?

Images:

[Translated view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu2Z0.png)

[Xcode structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBOMa.png)

Comment: Which one of the solutions have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I've used method 2 (I've edited the question)

Comment: @AitorSalvador Can you share the code of how you are reloading & from where you calling swapping.?